# how to make intent.setType for pdf,xlsx and txt file android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to choose only pdf, xlsx and txt file from storage but intent.setType can do only one file(eg.txt file only (or) pdf file only). Is it possible to get all three files by coding intent.setType() and Is there a way to do?

Here is some of my code.

```
  private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select txt file"),
                0);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog

    }
}
```

Comment: you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33117677/5597641

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pick few type of file via intent in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117592/how-to-pick-few-type-of-file-via-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 65):

@Fatehali Asamadi's way is OK, but need to add something for appropriate use. 
For Microsoft documents both (.doc or .docx), (.ppt or .pptx), (.xls or .xlsx) extensions are used. To support or browse these extensions you need to add more mimeTypes.

Use below method to browse documents where REQUEST_CODE_DOC is requestCode for onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode,final Intent data) @Override method.

```
private void browseDocuments(){

    String[] mimeTypes =
            {"application/msword","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx
                    "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", // .ppt & .pptx
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
                    "text/plain",
                    "application/pdf",
                    "application/zip"};

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
        if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        }
    } else {
        String mimeTypesStr = "";
        for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
            mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
        }
        intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0,mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
    }
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ChooseFile"), REQUEST_CODE_DOC);

}
```

You can get clear concept and add your required mimeTypes from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc/4212908#4212908)

Comment: I'm unable to see documents in-app while using this code. Can you help

Comment: My app supports Kitkat and above. So, I only use the first logic condition. However, somehow, it shows everything instead of just the intended ones. I am doubting about this line `intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");`. Doesn't it make it shows everything?

Comment: what is the purpose of that line ? intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");.

Comment: spent too much time looking for the docx Mime type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", which I needed to for CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile() allowedTypes parameter.  Thanks :)

Comment: use this code to detect mimetype

File file = new File(filePath);
        String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
        String mimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

Answer (score 22):

```
intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf|audio/*");
```

Maybe this is what you want.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? When I tried combining multiple types like this, the intent didn't select any file type.

Comment: yeah its more clear but doesnt work with '|' operator, i have tried and didnt work.

Comment: yes, same here. not working with "|"

Answer (score 12):

You should to check this link http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-any-type-of-file-with-default-intent.html. Also read through Mime Type.

This is how I have implemented for any file or selected mime type file

```
String[] mimeTypes =
{"image/*","application/pdf","application/msword","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","application/vnd.ms-excel","text/plain"};

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
    if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    }
} else {
    String mimeTypesStr = "";
    for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
        mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
    }
    intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0,mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
}
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ChooseFile"), 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you just want to see if those intents can be resolved.
This might be a better approach:

```
 private void showFileChooser() {

    Intent intentPDF = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intentPDF.setType("application/pdf");
    intentPDF.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    Intent intentTxt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intentTxt.setType("text/plain");
    intentTxt.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    Intent intentXls = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intentXls.setType("application/x-excel");
    intentXls.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    List activitiesPDF = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intentPDF,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    boolean isIntentSafePDF = activitiesPDF.size() > 0;

    List activitiesTxt = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intentTxt,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    boolean isIntentSafeTxt = activitiesTxt.size() > 0;

    List activitiesXls = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intentXls,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    boolean isIntentSafeXls = activitiesXls.size() > 0;

    if (!isIntentSafePDF || !isIntentSafeTxt || !isIntentSafeXls){

        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog

    }

}
```

References:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

[How do I determine if Android can handle PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784847/how-do-i-determine-if-android-can-handle-pdf/2790374#2790374)

Answer (score 6):

The simple solution is

```
   Intent gallery=new Intent();
        gallery.setType("application/*");
        gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(gallery,pick);
```

Note: pick is int variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT,

Each document is represented as a content:// URI backed by a `DocumentsProvider`, which can be opened as a stream with `openFileDescriptor(Uri, String)`, or queried for `DocumentsContract.Document` metadata.

All selected documents are returned to the calling application with persistable read and write permission grants. If you want to maintain access to the documents across device reboots, you need to explicitly take the persistable permissions using `takePersistableUriPermission(Uri, int)`.

Callers must indicate the acceptable document MIME types through `setType(String)`. For example, to select photos, use `image/*`. If multiple disjoint MIME types are acceptable, define them in `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` and `setType(String)` to `*/*`.

For the more details, please refer this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Note that this is only available on API Level 19+.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the kotlin way:

```
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
  val mimeType = arrayOf(
    "application/msword",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",  // .doc & .docx
    "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",  // .ppt & .pptx
    "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",  // .xls & .xlsx
    "text/plain",
    "application/pdf",
    "application/zip"
  ).joinToString("|")
  intent.type = mimeType
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
  val chooserIntent = Intent
    .createChooser(intent, fragment.getString(R.string.str_attachfile_chooser_message))
  launcher.launch(chooserIntent)
```

Launcher can be as:

```
val launcher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val intent = result.data
        // handle stuff here
    }
}
```