# How to filter out unwanted files using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-gallery

I'm using intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to allow a user to select images or video files only. this is the way am preparing my intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("image/* | video/*");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 XActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, ACQUIRE_IMAGE_AND_VIDEOS_CODE);
```

When i click the button that start this intent, the following apps are display in my customized dialog

[image: app dialog]

below is the method that fills my dialog with apps that can handle the above intent and also what happens when one clicks any app in the dialog

```
private void inflateDialog(List<ResolveInfo> intents){

ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Collections.sort(intents,
        new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));

appAdapter = new AppAdapter(packageManager, intents);

lv.setAdapter(appAdapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ResolveInfo launchable = appAdapter.getItem(position);
        ActivityInfo activity = launchable.activityInfo;
        ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                activity.name);
        IntentFilter filter = launchable.filter;

        Iterator<String> actions = filter.actionsIterator();

        Intent intent;

            if (filter.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)) {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/* | video/*");
                intent.setComponent(name);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                xActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, ACQUIRE_IMAGE_AND_VIDEOS_REQUEST_CODE);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
});
dialog.show();

}
```

When i click on galley app,i can see images and videos and select any. **AT the same time,** i receive a Toast telling me **0 images/videos available**.

When i click file manager and google drive, am presented with all files. **there is no filtering of images and videos that is taking place**.

**QUESTIONS**

- How can i force filtering of images and videos in file manager and google drive apps?
- Why am i receiving the toast **0 images/videos available** on galley even though i can select images and videos?

Comment: had u got the answer, as i am also not ableto filter it out.

Comment: @VikramSingh  see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way i could find to filter out unwanted files and deal with the ones i want. for my case, i only wanted videos and images.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

       String filePath;
       Uri file = intent.getData();
       String mimeType ="";

        if(file.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)){

            mimeType = ctx.getContentResolver().getType(selectedImage);

          }else{
           String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.toString());
           mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension.toLowerCase());
          }


           if(mimeType.startsWith("video/")){
             //do something. for my case i get video path
              filePath = getFilePath(file);


             }else if(mimeType.startsWith("image/")){
              //do something. for my case i get image path
               filePath = getFilePath(file);
             }
       }
 }
```

my getFilePath method

```
private String getFilePath(Uri fileuri){
String filePath = "";

if (fileuri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
  Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(fileuri, new String[]{android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  filePath = cursor.getString(0);

  cursor.close();
} else {
  filePath = fileuri.getPath();
}
  return filePath;
}
```