# Pick Image and Pdf using single intent

Tags: android

I know that we can use following

1. To Pick Images   :**intent.setType("image/*");**
2. To Pick PDF Files :**intent.setType("application/pdf");**

**So Is there any way by which we can pick any single entity either pdf or images through single intent?**

Comment: make it conditions where u want to open images make the intent for images  and so on..

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3645048/6127411.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/41015264/3470479

Answer (score 30, accepted):

here just an example:

```
private Intent getFileChooserIntent() {
    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
        if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        }
    } else {
        String mimeTypesStr = "";

        for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
            mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
        }

        intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0, mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
    }

    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why it's not accepted. It is the correct answer actually.

Comment: Execuse me, but hiw do I know the type of the selected file, if it's pdf or image ?

Answer (score 13):

Upper answer did not work in my case, after a hour trial-and-error, this is my working solution:

```
fun getFileChooserIntentForImageAndPdf(): Intent {
        val mimeTypes = arrayOf("image/*", "application/pdf")
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                .setType("image/*|application/pdf")
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
        return intent
    }
```

Hope can help someone.

Comment: awsome, it works , thank you so much , you saved me

Comment: You can avoid code duplication by `.setType(mimeTypes.joinToString(separator= "|"))`