# Pick a pdf and upload to server

Tags: android

I'm not able to pick pdf file from internal storage, external storage, recent or google sheet.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "application/pdf");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`,

Each document is represented as a content:// URI backed by a `DocumentsProvider`, which can be opened as a stream with `openFileDescriptor(Uri, String)`, or queried for DocumentsContract.Document metadata.

All selected documents are returned to the calling application with persistable read and write permission grants. If you want to maintain access to the documents across device reboots, you need to explicitly take the persistable permissions using `takePersistableUriPermission(Uri, int)`.

Callers must indicate the acceptable document MIME types through setType(String). For example, to select photos, use image/*. If multiple disjoint MIME types are acceptable, define them in `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` and `setType(String)` to /.

For the more details, please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)

Note that above mentioned is only available on API Level 19+.

Have a look at this also, [how to pick few type of file via intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117592/how-to-pick-few-type-of-file-via-intent-in-android/33117677#33117677)

Comment: I also want to run on 16 api level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    private static final int PICK_FILE = 101;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File"), PICK_FILE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

onActivityResult:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {

        case PICK_FILE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                // Get the path
                String path = getPath(mContext, uri);
                Log.d(TAG, "Path: " + path);
                if (path != null && path.contains(".pdf")) {

                } 
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

getPath:

```
    public String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = {"_data"};
            Cursor cursor;

            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                } 
                cursor.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Eat it
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }
```