# code template for uploading file code for android

Tags: android

I have been working on an android app that has uploading pictures and PDF files as one of its functions but i have a limited experience when it comes to the "uploading" activity for the PDF file (files excluding media files), although i have managed to successfully write the code for the "uploading" activity for images (part of that code can be found below). so the question is, what code template should i follow for the upload activity of the PDF file?
and if you have any advice on how to make the uploading procedure faster or optimized it would be greatly appreciated.

```
        case R.id.selectImageToUpload:
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            break;
        case R.id.selectFileToUpload:   break;
```

Comment: Have you tried to build your own URI in place of `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`?

Comment: hmm that is actually a good idea, would it be as fast tho (the performance)?

Comment: Have you tried this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978581/how-to-make-intent-settype-for-pdf-xlsx-and-txt-file-android or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945531/pick-any-kind-file-via-an-intent-on-android

Comment: It's just an Intent. The performance isn't the problem, it's finding the file

Comment: thanks a lot for the links, they are quite helpful, i am reading through them now.