# How to record audio and upload to server in android?How to restrict the particular file extensions using documents attachments?

Tags: android

Am working with android attachments same like whatsapp.I can able to take picture through camera,gallery options,location,record video.I have stucked with two options,

1. How to record audio?

while clicking on audio button,the following code i have been used,

```
        audioIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 6);

        }
    });
```

and which is redirecting to recording audio but after file save it is not redirecting to the activity.what is the code in onActivityResult .

2. How can i restrict the particular file extensions while attaching files,I need to select doc,txt,pdf,audio files.Rest i don't want to attach.I tried so many but i cant able to do.Please help me asp.This is my code after you mentioned link using,
   The following code i have been used,

   ```
   private void showFileChooser() 
   {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //        intent.setType("application/*");

     intent.setType("application/pdf|application/doc|appl‌​ication/docm|applica‌​tion/docx|applicatio‌​n/dot|application/mc‌​w|application/rtf" + "|application/pages|application/odt|application/ott");
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

       try 
       {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                4);
        } 
        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install a File Manager.",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: for question 2 , check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33117677/3983054

Comment: i have tried this...but still i can able to attach those files.

Comment: Post your complete codes , so that we can look into it

Comment: please look on to my code...when i do this i can able to select all files  intent.setType("application/*");...

Comment: But when i do this i cant able to select any file....intent.setType("application/pdf|application/doc|appl‌​ication/docm|applica‌​tion/docx|applicatio‌​n/dot|application/mc‌​w|application/rtf" + "|application/pages|application/odt|application/ott");

Comment: can you look into this answer once, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46074075/3983054

Comment: ya it worked.But in document i can able to take video image files etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154667/discussion-between-king-of-masses-and-sunisha-sindhu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For audio recording , Usually the normal Intent `MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION` will work to record the audio and return the path back to the activity in `onActivityResult()` method.

For that this the sample code.

```
 int RQS_RECORDING = 1;
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
 startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
```

In your `OnActivityResult()` your code will be like this,

```
 @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(requestCode == RQS_RECORDING){

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        // Great! User has recorded and saved the audio file

             if(data!=null) 
             {
             String  savedUri = data.getData();

            Log.d("debug" , "Record Path:" + savedUri);

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Saved: " + result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Oops! User has canceled the recording
    }
  }  
 }
```

But Nope, It is not working for all the cases and some of the devices ( ex vivo V3 etc)  recording is saved but it is not returning any data back i.e ( data is null) and some of the devices some additional options also in the recording ( like delete , retry , play , pause etc) which may also not required for us.

So Instead of the default Intent , you can create the custom Recording by using `MediaRecorder` like  below.

Sample Code.

AudioRecordActivity.Class

```
 public class AudioRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonStart, buttonStop ;
    String AudioSavePathInDevice = null;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder ;
    Random random ;
    String RandomAudioFileName = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.audio_record_activity);

        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonStop.setEnabled(false);

        random = new Random();

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(checkPermission()) {

                    AudioSavePathInDevice =
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                                    CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "AudioRecording.3gp";

                    MediaRecorderReady();

                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                    buttonStop.setEnabled(true);

                    Toast.makeText(AudioRecordActivity.this, "Recording started",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    requestPermission();
                }

            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(AudioRecordActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result",AudioSavePathInDevice);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    public void MediaRecorderReady(){
        mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
    }

    public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( string );
        int i = 0 ;
        while(i < string ) {
            stringBuilder.append(RandomAudioFileName.
                    charAt(random.nextInt(RandomAudioFileName.length())));

            i++ ;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AudioRecordActivity.this, new
                String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, RequestPermissionCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestPermissionCode:
                if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                    boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {
                        Toast.makeText(AudioRecordActivity.this, "Permission Granted",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AudioRecordActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                RECORD_AUDIO);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

audio_record_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Record"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="STOP"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

So where ever you want to record the audio / sound you can simply use the below code and get your saved path back in result activity.

```
int RQS_RECORDING = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , AudioRecordActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
```

`OnActivityResult()` will be like this

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode == RQS_RECORDING){

            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                // Great! User has recorded and saved the audio file
                String result=data.getStringExtra("result");

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Saved: " + result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               Log.d("debug" , "Saved Path::" + result);


            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Oops! User has canceled the recording / back button
            }

        }

    }
```

This is a sample code you can customize for your needs how you want for your requirement.

[This](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioRecorder) is one library which providing the record controlling

For the second question, as i already given the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46074075/3983054), you can use like below.

```
private void browseDocuments(){

    String[] mimeTypes =
            {"application/msword","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx
                    "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", // .ppt & .pptx
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
                    "text/plain",
                    "application/pdf",
                    "application/zip"};

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
        if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        }
    } else {
        String mimeTypesStr = "";
        for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
            mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
        }
        intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0,mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
    }
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ChooseFile"), REQUEST_CODE_DOC);

}
```